node js file path problem (windows, plesk)
I am using plesk on windows server. I have a nodejs project running smoothly on localhost, but there is a problem on windows server as follows
app.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const index = require('./routes/index');
const api = require('./routes/api');
const { mongoURI } = require('./config'); // MongoDB URI

const app = express();

// MongoDB bağlantısı
mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB bağlantısı başarılı.');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('MongoDB bağlantı hatası:', err);
});

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Statik dosyalar ve rotalar
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', api);

// Hatalı rota
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('404', { message: 'Sayfa bulunamadı.' });
});

// Sunucuyu başlat
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Sunucu çalışıyor: http://localhost:${port}`);
});

index.ejs file in views folder
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Müşteri Sözleşme Sistemi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/output.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

It works smoothly on the local host in this way, but I need to update the code as follows to work in the windows server. how can I fix this problem in this way in all areas
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Müşteri Sözleşme Sistemi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..public/stylesheets/output.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

